# Riofs - fuse device not found

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, fuse

I am trying to run riofs inside a docker container, however when I try to run riofs I get the following error:

```
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
ERROR! Failed to mount FUSE partition !
ERROR! Failed to create FUSE fs ! Mount point: /path/to/dir
```

Here is what my DockerFile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y \
            build-essential \
            gcc \
            make \
            automake \
            autoconf \
            libtool \
            pkg-config \
            intltool \
            libglib2.0-dev \
            libfuse-dev \
            libxml2-dev \
            libevent-dev \
            libssl-dev \
            && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

    RUN curl -L https://github.com/skoobe/riofs/archive/v${VERSION}.tar.gz | tar zxv -C /usr/src
    RUN cd /usr/src/riofs-${VERSION} && ./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install

    WORKDIR /opt/riofs/bin

    CMD ["bash"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add the runtime privilege SYS_ADMIN because fuse needs permissions to mount/umount.

```
docker run -it --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse [IMAGE] bash
```